# Creating Multiple Balls That Wrap Around Pane

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

Would like to first state that I am a computer science student and my University is **strict on direct code copying** so if you could please **refrain** from answers such as **"it should look like this"** it would be greatly appreciated. So basically my assignment is to create a JavaFX program that contains multiple green balls, and one red ball. All the balls must wrap around the pane (in an asteroids type of way) and if a red ball happens to collide with the green ball, the green ball is removed. I have multiple issues, but the key one I need to focus on is how to get all the balls from my ArrayList along with my one red ball to show up in the pane and move independently. They are all there in the pane (and bounce currently) but its like they are all bound together. I have given each ball random xy values and they should also all have random dx/dy values(their velocity). And I believe that is where my problem lies, each ball does not have their own dx/dy, thus I created a class that extends `Circle` to try and solve that problem but my getters and setters do not seem to be accessible. I also know the root of the problem lies in the `moveBall()` method as it is the method that needs to adjust values, but I cannot figure out the algorithm, and since my professor's office hours are over, I have came here in hopes of someone pointing me in the right direction. Here are the classses(I would also like to state, this is not fully my code; it's modified code from a Case Study exercise from "Intro To Java Programming 10th ed. by Y. Daniel Liang):

EDIT: Corrected a small error. Main problem is getting all the balls to now move independently via the `moveBall()` method.

EDIT 2: Assignment is OVER. Answers are are no longer restricted. Also added other methods that are not doing what I want `addBallToPane()` and `checkForCollision()` If anyone can tell me how I could repair these that would be great. Still want to solve this on my own, but with help :)

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;



 public class BallPane extends Pane {

        MovementGenerator mG = new MovementGenerator();
        public final double radius = 20;
        private double x = mG.position(), y = mG.position();
        private double dx = mG.velocity(), dy = mG.velocity();
        private Circle predator = new MovableCircle(x, y, radius, Color.RED);
        private Timeline animation;
        ArrayList<MovableCircle> circles = new ArrayList<>();

        public BallPane() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                circles.add(i, new MovableCircle(x, y, radius, Color.GREEN));
                circles.get(i).setDx(dx);
                circles.get(i).setDy(dy);
            }
            getChildren().addAll(circles);
            predator.setFill(Color.RED);
            getChildren().add(predator);

            // Create an animation for moving the ball
            animation = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5), e -> moveBall()));
            animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            animation.play(); // Start animation
        }

        public void play() {
            animation.play();

        }

        public void pause() {
            animation.pause();
        }

        public void increaseSpeed() {
            animation.setRate(animation.getRate() + 0.1);
        }

        public void decreaseSpeed() {
            animation.setRate(
                    animation.getRate() > 0 ? animation.getRate() - 0.1 : 0);

        }

public void addBallToPane() {
         incrementalEnding++;                                 
         circles.add(new MovableCircle(radius, Color.GREEN));               
         getChildren().add(circles.get(incrementalEnding));

    }

    public void checkForCollison() {

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {                  
            if ((predator.intersects(circles.get(i).getBoundsInLocal()))) {
                getChildren().remove(circles.get(i));
            }
        }

    protected void moveBall() {
        // Check boundaries
        if (x < radius || x > getWidth() - radius) {
            dx *= -1; // Change ball move direction
        }
        if (y < radius || y > getHeight() - radius) {
            dy *= -1; // Change ball move direction   
        }
        // Adjust ball position
        for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
            circles.get(i).setCenterX(x);
            circles.get(i).setCenterY(y);
        }
        predator.setCenterX(x);
        predator.setCenterY(y);

    }

}
```

Side note: I wanna set the dx/dy as the objects are created in the ArrayList, but as I stated my accessors and mutators are not accessible.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

public class BounceBallControl extends Application {
  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    BallPane ballPane = new BallPane(); // Create a ball pane

    // Pause and resume animation
//    ballPane.setOnMousePressed(e -> ballPane.pause());
//    ballPane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> ballPane.play());

    // Increase and decrease animation   
    ballPane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
      if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
        ballPane.increaseSpeed();
      } 
      else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
        ballPane.decreaseSpeed();
      }
    });



    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(ballPane, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("BounceBallControl"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

    // Must request focus after the primary stage is displayed
    ballPane.requestFocus();
  }

  /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class MovableCircle extends Circle{

   MovementGenerator mG = new MovementGenerator();
   private double dx, dy;


   MovableCircle(double x, double y, double radius, Color color){
       super(x, y, radius);
       setFill(color);
   } 

    public double getDx() {
        return dx;
    }

    public void setDx(double newDx) {
        if (newDx < -10 || newDx > 10) {
            newDx = mG.velocity();
        } else {
          dx = newDx;  
        }   
    }

    public double getDy() {
        return dy;
    }

    public void setDy(double newDy) {
       if (newDy < -10 || newDy > 10) {
            newDy = mG.velocity();
        } else {
          dy = newDy;  
        }   
    }


}
```

This next class doesn't do much besides generate random values, probably didn't need to make a whole new class for its function but eh. And it is just here for reference just in case:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MovementGenerator {

    private static int movement;
    private static int spawnPoint;
    Random rand = new Random();


    MovementGenerator(){
        movement = 0;
        spawnPoint = 0;
    }

    public static int getMovement() {
        return movement;
    }

    public static void setMovement(int movement) {
        MovementGenerator.movement = movement;
    }

    public static int getSpawnPoint() {
        return spawnPoint;
    }

    public static void setSpawnPoint(int spawnPoint) {
        MovementGenerator.spawnPoint = spawnPoint;
    }

    public int velocity(){
        movement = rand.nextInt(1);
        if (movement == 1) {
            movement = rand.nextInt(10);
        }
        else if (movement == 0) {
            movement = (rand.nextInt(10)*-1);
        }
        return movement;
    }

    public int position(){
        return spawnPoint = rand.nextInt(500);

    }
}
```

Comment: Make the reference type to the ball `MoveableCircle` instead of `Circle`. You won't be able to see `MoveableCircle`-specific methods (i.e. `getDx()` etc) via a `Circle` reference.

Comment: What are `x`, `y`, `dx`, and `dy` in the `BallPane` class supposed to represent? That's really unclear. If you want each ball to move independently, I would start by defining a `move()` method in the `MoveableCircle` class...

Comment: `x` and `y` are values that I am using as arguments in my parameter list as my new Circles objects are created. To get each object to have different xy coordinates I just set the values to a RNG with numbers that are only allowed within the program. To be honest, I am still trying to figure out myself what `dx` and `dy` are, as sad as that is. As I said, I am just modifying code from my text book. The `moveBall()` method that is defined in `BallPane` is virtually untouched by me, I just added the `for` loop thinking more balls would appear.

Comment: I know originally that the `dx` and `dy` values reversed the order at which the objects are repainted (i.e. making them bounce off the pane). So I had thought by modifying this code and giving each new object its own `dx` and `dy` they would all appear separately in the pane and bounce independently. Know I don't know what the hell is going on.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer to give you the chance to start dealing with your project...

Following James_D suggestion, not only you need a `moveBall` method in `MovableCircle`, but also you need to get rid of `x`,`y`,`dx`,`dy` on `BallPane`, and transfer the control to each ball.

This is what I think should be done for starters:

**MovableCircle**

```
public class MovableCircle extends Circle {

   private final MovementGenerator mG = new MovementGenerator();
   private double x = mG.position(), y = mG.position();
   private double dx = mG.velocity(), dy = mG.velocity();
   private final double radius; 

   MovableCircle(double radius, Color color){
       this.setCenterX(x);
       this.setCenterY(y);
       this.radius=radius;
       this.setRadius(radius);
       this.setFill(color);
       setDx(dx);
       setDy(dy);
   } 

    public double getDx() { return dx; }

    public final void setDx(double newDx) {
        while (newDx < -10 || newDx > 10) {
            newDx = mG.velocity();
        } 
        dx = newDx;  
    }

    public double getDy() { return dy; }

    public final void setDy(double newDy) {
       while(newDy < -10 || newDy > 10) {
            newDy = mG.velocity();
        } 
        dy = newDy;  
    }

    public void moveBall() {
        // Check boundaries
        if (x < radius || x > BounceBallControl.WIDTH - radius) {
            dx *= -1; // Change ball move direction
        }
        if (y < radius || y > BounceBallControl.HEIGHT - radius) {
            dy *= -1; // Change ball move direction   
        }
        // Adjust ball position
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        setCenterX(x);
        setCenterY(y);
    }

}
```

**BallPane**

```
public class BallPane extends Pane {

    public final double radius = 20;
    private final MovableCircle predator = new MovableCircle(radius, Color.RED);
    private final Timeline animation;
    private final List<MovableCircle> circles;

    public BallPane() {
        circles=IntStream.range(0,10).mapToObj(i->new MovableCircle(radius, Color.GREEN))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        getChildren().addAll(circles);
        predator.setFill(Color.RED);
        getChildren().add(predator);

        setWidth(BounceBallControl.WIDTH);
        setHeight(BounceBallControl.HEIGHT);

        // Create an animation for moving the ball
        animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), e -> moveBall()));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play(); // Start animation
    }

    public final void moveBall() {
        circles.forEach(MovableCircle::moveBall);
        predator.moveBall();

    }
    ...
}
```

where

```
public class BounceBallControl extends Application {

    public static final int WIDTH  = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 500;
    ...
}
```

Run and you'll find something like this:

[image: Snapshot of the game]

Now it's time to figure out the way to remove green balls...

Comment: This really goes against what my intro stated. But don't let that undermine my appreciation, I'm just afraid to use your structure in any way. But I do thank you for providing a reference I can try to understand. I understand practically everything you have provide, save for the first line of the `BallPane` class you provided. I'm not familiar with any of those method calls. Any way you could elaborate what that's doing. At first glance it looks to be expanding the list. Is this correct?

Comment: I didn't mean to put you in trouble by showing some code. On the contrary, I thought you needed some push, as you weren't able to figure out the way to generate proper moving balls, as you state also in your intro. On using Java 8 new features (the `IntStream` line, and others), you have the chance to do it your way with traditional ways (a for-loop, ...), so you can't exactly copy my code. If you need more help, just ask, but this is a place where answers are better shown with code...

Comment: I understand, I could have been more specific. However could you be so kind to elaborate more on the `IntStream`? I read up on it before I used it. But like with most things I'm just learning, I tend to use things without full comprehension of what they do. From what I gather The `IntStream` is using its `range()` method to set elements from index 0 to where ever, and then for each element the lambda expression creates the number of objects defined in the range, and then they are added to a list. Is this about right or is there something deeper going on with the collectors?

Comment: [`IntStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) is the `int` primitive specialization of `Stream`. With `range` you get a sequential ordered `IntStream` from 0 (inclusive) to 10 (exclusive) by an incremental step of 1. Then `mapToObject` creates for every step a moving circle. What we have after that is a stream of objects (circles). With `collect` we group this stream into a `List`. In other words, this is the same as your old for-loop going from 0 to 9 to add a circle to the list on every step, but using Java 8.

Comment: Gotchya. Is this more beneficial in anyway? Also if I wanted to add new elements to this collection dynamically, is it as simple as modifying the exclusive value and then retrieving the new element? Also, I know this is bordering an in depth discussion, but I just want to make sure I understand this.

Comment: For starters you can parallelize the stream (since you don't need an ordered list of circles), though `parallel()` must be used with great care. To add more elements or modify them, you operate over the list as before, but now taken as a stream, with some `filter` to select the elements to be modified based on some condition, and `forEach` to apply the modifications to the selected elements. Have a look at some tutorial to learn about the new features of Java 8.

Comment: @ZFN7 note that it doesn't make sense to pass the `Pane` as a parameter to `moveBall` every time you move a ball, just to check its position within the limits of the game. By using static variables, these limits are defined at the beginning of the game (assuming they are not changing), and they define the size of the pane and the scene, and also they are used to check the balls at any time.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah I'm feeling kinda stupid now that I tested it and see it does not work. I saw a fellow classmates design, and it incorporated a parameter. Looked cleaner then the typecast. Learned a lesson in testing functionality before an edit to save my self from embarrassment.